# Returning a variable from an if-else statement to the main program

Tags: java

I am writing a program which gives the cmyk output when you put in rgb values.

I did Python before Java, so I'm currently a java noob.
Apparently variables within if-else statments can't be passed onto the main program. In blueJ, it says "cannot find variable `c`"

```
public class color_conversion
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int g = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        if ((r == 0 && g == 0)&&(g == 0 && b == 0))
        {
            double c = 0;
            double m = 0;
            double y = 0;
            double k = 0;
        }
        else         
        {
            int w = (int)(Math.max(r/255,(Math.max(g/255,b/255))));
            double c = (double)((w-(r/255))/w);
            double m = (double)((w-(g/255))/w);
            double y = (double)((w-(b/255))/w);
            double k = (double)(1-w);
        }
        System.out.println("cyan    =" + c);
        System.out.println("magenta =" + m);
        System.out.println("yellow  =" + y);
        System.out.println("black   =" + k);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're declaring: double c = 0; inside of an if statement.

Comment: Declare them in outside the if else block.

Comment: variables created in the if scope are not hoisted up to the scope of the parent, they are only visible within it. maybe this will help http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: wondering why this is being downvoted. is the question asked before/too basic? I can understand that basic programming questions on this site get a lot of answers and downvotes. is that what this is?

Comment: "*wondering why this is being downvoted*" it probably got down-voted because it is about basic concept which exists in many languages -  ***scope***. Many people see it as lack of research which is valid reason for down-vote (hover your mouse over down-vote arrow and you will see when it should be used).

Comment: @Pshemo seems legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define all the variables `c`, `m`, `y` and `k` twice - once in `if`, once in `else` block, making them local for those blocks only.

You need to define these variables on the same level as `r`, `g` and `b` and just assign values in `if` or `else` block.

So it would look like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    double c;
    double m;
    double y;
    double k;

    if ((r == 0 && g == 0)&&(g == 0 && b == 0))
    {
        c = 0;
        m = 0;
        y = 0;
        k = 0;
    }
    else         
    {
        int w = (int)(Math.max(r/255,(Math.max(g/255,b/255))));
        c = (double)((w-(r/255))/w);
        m = (double)((w-(g/255))/w);
        y = (double)((w-(b/255))/w);
        k = (double)(1-w);
    }
    System.out.println("cyan    =" + c);
    System.out.println("magenta =" + m);
    System.out.println("yellow  =" + y);
    System.out.println("black   =" + k);
}
```

Comment: The logic in the `if` conditional can can shortened to `r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0`.

Comment: Right, it could be `if (r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0)`, but that was not part of OP's question, so I didn't touch it... also, the `if` body could be just  `c = m = y = k = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

declare your variables before `if`, as you did with `r`, `g` and `b`.
So it would be

```
double c;
double m;
...
```

they will be local for whole main method. Now use them inside `if` without the type (if you put type you would declare new variable local for this if with the same name.) like this

c = 0;

At the moment you made two local sets of c, m, y and k (each local to it's own block)

Answer (score 1):

Declare them out side of `if-else` block. Other wise compiler will treat them as local variables.

```
        double c;
        double m;
        double y;
        double k;

 if ((r == 0 && g == 0)&&(g == 0 && b == 0))
    {
        c = 0;
        m = 0;
        y = 0;
        k = 0;
    }
    else         
    {
        int w = (int)(Math.max(r/255,(Math.max(g/255,b/255))));
        c = (double)((w-(r/255))/w);
        m = (double)((w-(g/255))/w);
        y = (double)((w-(b/255))/w);
        k = (double)(1-w);
    }
```

Comment: The logic in the `if` statement can be shortened.

Comment: in single line `c = m = y = k = 0`. @RobertBain

Comment: In the condition, should I say.

Comment: I.E. `r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0`

Comment: thats right.. if all thse 3 variables are equals to `0` then `if` true. @RobertBain

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the variables outside like this:

```
public class color_conversion
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{


    double c = 0;
    double m = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double k = 0;
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    if (r != 0 || g != 0 || b != 0)        
    {
        int w = (int)(Math.max(r/255,(Math.max(g/255,b/255))));
        c = (double)((w-(r/255))/w);
        m = (double)((w-(g/255))/w);
        y = (double)((w-(b/255))/w);
        k = (double)(1-w);
    }
    System.out.println("cyan    =" + c);
    System.out.println("magenta =" + m);
    System.out.println("yellow  =" + y);
    System.out.println("black   =" + k);
}
}
```

Comment: There are holes in the scope in the `if` statement.

Comment: I think I fixed it. now?

Answer (score 1):

In Java all variables and objects have a **scope** that mean that a variable/object only lives in this scope. In your example, the **c** variable only exists inside the if statement. When the flow exists from the if statement, the **c** variable is recollected by GC.

So, just move the **c, m, k, y** variables at top of main function.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem:

You take integer division like 'r/255', which most of time gives you '0'. 
To solve this you should cast one of them to 'double', likes

```
(double)r/255
```

Or

```
r/255.0
```

Or

```
r/(double)255
```

or cast both of them.

Comment: Yeah, this was another one of my problems. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks. It prints NaN for 3 of the values. How do I fix this?